# Find previous table row with class

Tags: jquery

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr class="gotChild">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr class="gotChild">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr class="gotChild">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
    <tr class="gotParent">...</tr>
</table>
```

Inside the `.gotParent` rows are (obviously) table cells with buttons inside it. When clicking it, I want to affect the nearest `.gotChild` table row.

If the `.gotChild` is the direct previous row, it's easy enough, I use:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var gotChild = $(this).parent().parent().prev('.gotChild');
}
```

But if there are more `.gotParent` rows as previous rows, this function doesn't work.

Using `.prevAll()` affect all the `.gotChild` rows (should only be the first it finds.

Using `.prevUntill()` affects all the table rows where it should only affect the `.gotChild` row.

How can I target this specific row?

Comment: Something like this `$(this).parent().parent().prevAll(".gotChild:first");`

Comment: `prevAll(".gotChild:first")` did the trick. Thank you @ValeryViktorovsky. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great! I added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select closest previous sibling using code bellow:

```
var gotChild = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll(".gotChild:first");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).prevAll(".gotChild").eq(0);
```

will only select the first matching value